# 'Calculation' tag: merge, burninate, or leave alone?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

On StackOverflow, the [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate) tag was marked "DO NOT USE" in the tag cleanup this summer.  Despite this it still gets questions posted to it; I noticed 100+ earlier today, which seemed a manageable number, so I've been going through them and editing where appropriate and simply retagging when not.

However in this process, I just noticed that there is also a [calculation](/questions/tagged/calculation) tag, which was *not* marked "DO NOT USE" in the tag cleanup.  Unlike [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate), it has 692 questions.  There's no way I'm editing/retagging all of those.  So...  Should the [calculation](/questions/tagged/calculation) tag be merged with the [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate) tag?  Neither have a tag wiki (well, calculate has the "DO NOT USE" tag wiki) and they seem pretty similar and both useless.  But if we just merge them, then we have 700+ questions under a "do not use" tag, which seems like we're, well, *using* it.  So maybe it should be burninated instead?  Or maybe it has value I'm missing and should be kept. Still trying to wrap my head around what tags are actually useless and which ones just seem useless to me, and I appreciate meta's help in this matter.  Both [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate) and [calculation](/questions/tagged/calculation) seem like meta-tags to me, though, based on the explanation I was linked to earlier this evening.

Comment: Or maybe we should all just have a beer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey LOL. Should I just leave the tags alone? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 2):

I merged [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate) with [calculation](/questions/tagged/calculation).

Comment: I don't think it is status-completed, though. There hasn't been any discussion on whether it should stay or not.

Comment: It's not a particularly useful tag, but it's not actively harmful, either, IMO.  I certainly don't think it's worth the effort to revisit 692 questions, and it's not egregious enough to be blacklisted.

Comment: What you said make sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I struggle to find any meaning in that tag. Unlike many tags mentioned in tag lineup, this one looks like a good candidate for burninating. What does this tag mean?

Comment: If you mean blacklisting, a dev is required for that.  I only ask devs to burn the really harmful tags.